# Push item to every associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
function array_push_multi_assoc($array, $key, $key2, $value){
    $array[$key][$key2] = $value;
    return $array;
}

$myarray = array_push_multi_assoc($myarray, $key=0, 'subject', 'hello');

print_r($myarray);

    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 97
            [email] => vikastyagismartbuzz8@gmail.com
            [subject] => hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 93
            [email] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 94
            [email] => vikastyagismartbuzz9@gmail.com
        )

)
```

I want to have something like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 97
            [email] => vikastyagismartbuzz8@gmail.com
            [subject] => hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 93
            [email] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
            [subject] => hello
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 94
            [email] => vikastyagismartbuzz9@gmail.com
            [subject] => hello
        )

)
```

Comment: This can achieved by simple foreach loop and adding index,values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can be used to build a new array, after applying a function to an existing one:

```
$newArray = array_map(function($row) {
    $row['subject'] = 'hello';
    return $row;
}, $oldArray);
```

Or use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to manipulate the existing one:

```
array_walk($oldArray, function(&$row) {
    $row['subject'] = 'hello';
});
```

Note, you can rewrite either of these functions in a way that will mean their roles are reversed (e.g. building a new array with array_walk) but the examples above are how each should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Though it might have been achieved with loop through elements, the more applicable and powerful way is to use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
array_map(function($item) { $item['subject'] = 'hello'; }, $array)
```

Hope it helps.